# Java applet or a custom browser plugin?

Tags: java, python, applet

We're writing a platform for building apps that are able to run on any browser and we were thinking, is there a way to do this with Python? Or should we better go with Java and Java Applets?

I was also wondering, how hard is it to write a custom browser plugin? How long would it take e.g. in man-hours?

Thank you!

Comment: "How long would it take e.g. in man-hours?"  42.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to create a browser plug-in using Java, but applets are certainly not the answer.  An applet is a guest in a web page, not a browser plug-in.

Comment: Maybe browser plugin is the wrong phrase, I mean the "thing" like ActiveX, or Unity Web Player [link](http://unity3d.com/webplayer/) etc) that allow you to use native resources like the webcam. How hard is it to build one of those ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The universal API for browser addons is javascript. It is well supported in Firefox, Chromium/Chrome, and Opera at least; it is the only extension API available on the last two. Intersting API subsets are firefox's Fuel, Chromium's trimmed down extension api, and the very portable GreaseMonkey functions.

A second runtime would have its own startup costs, garbage heap, and ffi overhead. It would require special privileges, and would still have to translate its API calls into javascript. That would make it fairly unattractive.

Edit: you were asking about web content with possible plugin or addon support? You also have the option of the NPAPI (also the Pepper project around it). This api is C-level and can render to a rectangular area on its own (using OS APIs), at the cost of very little support from the browser and being a portability nightmare.

Comment: Hi Tobu, as I explained in my comment above, I probably used the wrong phrase: I mean stuff like Unity Web Player that you install and allow you to use native resources. Any info on how and if it's possible to build one of those ? Thank you!

Comment: Look at Google Gears, which uses the NPAPI approach and was recently retired in favor of all-html5 implementations.